# Generating structs with one thread and receiving in different thread with selector

Tags: c, multithreading, selector

I'm generating "event" structs in one thread and sending them back to the main thread in several-second intervals. Naturally it doesn't work right. I have two questions:

1. Why do I get a bazillion event received messages in my select loop? Do I need to read from the pipe so the file descriptor no longer says there is stuff there?
2. How do I pull the reference to the struct out of the pipe?

Desired Output:

```
$ ...
Writing event 1 to pipe
Received event on pipe
Writing event 2 to pipe
Received event on pipe
```

Acutal Output:

```
$ ...
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event on pipe
Received event o^C
```

GCC command:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

test.c:

```
/* Simple example with two threads and a pipe. One thread writes structs to a 
   pipe every few seconds; the other reads the structs, prints out their info
   and then frees the structs
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

void mywait(int timeInSec);

// The events
typedef struct event {
    int id;
    int data;
} event_t;

int id = 0;
int pipefd[2];

void* pump(void *arg) { // Generates events

    for (;;)
    {
        mywait(1); // sleep thread

        printf("writing event #%i to pipe\n", id);

        // generate event
        event_t *event;
        event = malloc(sizeof(*event));
        memset(event, 0, sizeof(*event));
        event->id = id++;

        // write event to pipe
        write(pipefd[1], &event, sizeof(event));

        // NOTE: Free event in other thread
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Starting pipe_test.c\n");

    // 1. Create a pipe
    pipe(pipefd);

    // 2. Create thread to pump events into pipe
    pthread_t tid;
    if (pthread_create( &tid, NULL, pump, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create:pump");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // 3. Set up selector in main thread to read events off pipe
    int z;
    fd_set readfds; //readable file descriptor
    int selectmax;
    selectmax = pipefd[0] + 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        // Initialize selector
        FD_ZERO( &readfds );
        FD_SET( pipefd[0], &readfds );
        z = select( selectmax, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL );

        if( z < 0 ) {
            printf( "select() failed\n");
            // close( pipefd ); //???
            return 1;
        } else {
            if( FD_ISSET( pipefd[0], &readfds ) ) {
                printf("Received event on pipe\n"); // I get a shitton of these

                // Get the pointer to the event struct from the pipe
                // TODO: GOOD WAY TO DO THIS?

                // Free the struct
                // TODO
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// From http://somethingswhichidintknow.blogspot.com/2009/09/sleep-in-pthread.html
pthread_mutex_t fakeMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t fakeCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void mywait(int timeInSec)
{
    struct timespec timeToWait;
    struct timeval now;
    int rt;
    gettimeofday(&now,NULL);

    timeToWait.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + timeInSec;
    timeToWait.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec*1000;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&fakeMutex);
    rt = pthread_cond_timedwait(&fakeCond, &fakeMutex, &timeToWait);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fakeMutex);
}
```

Comment: +1 just for 'Naturally it doesn't work right' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, you need to actually read the data. Also note that you need to allocate memory for the entire structure, not just for the pointer (i.e., `event = malloc(sizeof(event_t));`).

```
/* Simple example with two threads and a pipe. One thread writes structs to a 
   pipe every few seconds; the other reads the structs, prints out their info
   and then frees the structs
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

void mywait(int timeInSec);

// The events
typedef struct event {
    int id;
    int data;
} event_t;

int id = 0;
int pipefd[2];

void* pump(void *arg) { // Generates events

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("writing event #%i to pipe\n", id);

        // generate event
        event_t *event;
        event = malloc(sizeof(event_t));
        memset(event, 0, sizeof(event_t));
        event->id = id++;

        // write event to pipe
        int nbytes = write(pipefd[1], &event, sizeof(event_t*));
        //printf("written %d bytes.\n", nbytes);

        // NOTE: Free event in other thread
        mywait(1); // sleep thread
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Starting pipe_test.c\n");

    // 1. Create a pipe
    pipe(pipefd);

    // 2. Create thread to pump events into pipe
    pthread_t tid;
    if (pthread_create( &tid, NULL, pump, NULL) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create:pump");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // 3. Set up selector in main thread to read events off pipe
    int z;
    fd_set readfds; //readable file descriptor
    int selectmax;
    selectmax = pipefd[0] + 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        // Initialize selector
        FD_ZERO( &readfds );
        FD_SET( pipefd[0], &readfds );
        z = select( selectmax, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL );

        if( z < 0 ) {
            printf( "select() failed\n");
            // close( pipefd ); //???
            return 1;
        } else {
            if( FD_ISSET( pipefd[0], &readfds ) ) {
                printf("Received event on pipe\n"); // I get a shitton of these

                // Get the pointer to the event struct from the pipe
                event_t* received_event = NULL;
                int nbytes = read(pipefd[0], &received_event, sizeof(event_t*));
                printf("read %d bytes\n", nbytes);
                if (nbytes > 0)
                    printf("Event id: %d\n", received_event->id);

                // Free the struct
                free(received_event);
            }
        }

        mywait(1); // sleep thread
    }

    return 0;
}

// From http://somethingswhichidintknow.blogspot.com/
// 2009/09/sleep-in-pthread.html
pthread_mutex_t fakeMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t fakeCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void mywait(int timeInSec)
{
    struct timespec timeToWait;
    struct timeval now;
    int rt;
    gettimeofday(&now,NULL);

    timeToWait.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + timeInSec;
    timeToWait.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec*1000;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&fakeMutex);
    rt = pthread_cond_timedwait(&fakeCond, &fakeMutex, &timeToWait);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&fakeMutex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you must read from the pipe, or it will be forever stay readable.
2. Use `read` to read into a structure, just like you do with write.

There are a couple of other points too: First are actually sending the address of the pointer, not the actual pointer. Second, you don't have to dynamically allocate the structure, just allocate on the stack and send the structure.

Answer (score 0):

`select` only tells you that there is data available.  You have to `read` the data to get it off the descriptor. I would also recommend that you add a little bit of information to your debug (a time stamp at minimum) so that you can see the breadth of data creation :)